# cant push string in eval array

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to push string into array  by eval definition

```
    jsn_obj=[{"row":1,"integerz":1,"stringz":"a"},{"row":2,"integerz":2,"stringz":"b"}];
var getz = jsn_obj;
    for (var i = 0, length = getz.length; i < length; i++)
    {
    console.log(getz[i].row);
    eval("window.int_array_"+getz[i].row+"=[]");
    eval("window.string_array_"+getz[i].row+"=[]");
    eval("int_array_"+getz[i].row+".push("+getz[i].integerz+")");
    eval("string_array_"+getz[i].row+".push("+getz[i].stringz+")");
    console.log(eval("int_array_"+getz[i].row));
    console.log(eval("string_array_"+getz[i].row));

    }
```

Im, trying to create array from loop and initialize it as per jsonobj/values but am getting reference error while pushing string(while it accepts string that contains digits only for instance:"123") Am unable to identify what is wrong with the code.. thanks in advance.

Comment: It is hard to understand why you are using eval for this in the first place. You don't need to use it. You are making your code more complicated and less optimized!

Comment: Sorry Hirad Nikoo.. actually for generation of arrays as per json row value , i was using eval,i must say using eval was making it unnecessarily complex.Thank you Hitmands,nicematt,Hirad Nikoo..

Comment: Your're welcome. Glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you don't need for `eval`, you just need to study how access to object properties... 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

```js
var jsn_obj=[
  {"row":1,"integerz":1,"stringz":"a"},
  {"row":2,"integerz":2,"stringz":"b"}
];

var getz = jsn_obj; // ?

for (var i = 0, length = getz.length; i < length; i++)
{
  var intArrayProp = "int_array_" + getz[i].row;
  var stringArrayProp = "string_array_" + getz[i].row;
  
  if(!Array.isArray(window[intArrayProp])) {
    window[intArrayProp] = [];
  }
    
  if(!Array.isArray(window[stringArrayProp])) {
    window[stringArrayProp] = [];
  }
  
  window[intArrayProp].push( getz[i].integerz );
  window[stringArrayProp].push( getz[i].stringz );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I won't update this answer until I get op objective.</sub>

---

The String `getz[i].stringz` is concatenated without quotes, being a identifier name. View example:

```
string_array_1.push(a)
```

but expected:

```
string_array_1.push("a")
```

You could put quotes around it

```
eval("string_array_" + getz[i].row + ".push('" + getz[i].stringz + "')");
```

In this way the browser will certainly throw errors. Consider `JSON.stringify` method, which will return the string raw.

(Note by @NiettheDarkAbsol.)

```
eval("string_array_" + getz[i].row + ".push(" + JSON.stringify(getz[i].stringz) + ")");
```

Comment: Fails if string contains further quotes. Consider using `... ".push("+JSON.stringify(getz[i].stringz)+")"`, although obviously "not using `eval()`" is better.